# On Android, how do you switch activities programmatically?

Tags: android, android-activity

It seems like every example I can find of switching between activities involves creating an Intent and passing in the context of a View via an OnClickListener associated with a button.

But what if you just decide you need to switch activities? In my case, a preference value is causing an Activity switch.

How do you create an Intent that can cause an Activity switch without an associated OnClickListener?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivityName.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

You can call that from anywhere in your current activity.

Comment: is it possible to pass activity name as a String?

Comment: @Mohammad Not according to any of the public signatures I've seen, but what you could do is use `Class.forName(fully qualified class name)` to return a `Class` object and then pass that `Class` object to the `Intent` constructor.

Comment: create a method that reads user input and uses it's substring as a parameter to call another class through reflection would be a terrible idea

Answer (score 9):

It depends where you want to start the new activity in the code. You need the access to a Context reference to start a new activity( For example: onPostExecute in AsyncTask). Please have a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518206/what-is-the-difference-between-activity-and-context)**.

Even though it is basically this.

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityName.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

It can be something like this as well

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityName.class);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: I found funny how you made the exact same typo as the accepted answer with the class name `AvitivityName` ;) You could have just point that in a comment you know :)

Answer (score 5):

I have the shortest Version

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,ActivityYouWantToOpen.class));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
startActivity (new Intent (Thisactivity.this, Nextactivity.class));
```

Don't forget  to add activity to your manifest

```
<Activity android:name=".NextActivity>
```

Answer (score 3):

when ever u want to switch activity . u can call these code .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can write this code in PreferenceChangeListener.

Comment: you dupicated the other guys answer exactly ... come up with you rown answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `intent` in the main activity like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, second.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you are waiting for result from the second then you should use

`StartActivityforresult(intent,request code)`.

Request code can be any `integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Use PreferenceChangeListener :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to create UI for a button by using layout intro_activity_1.XML file. After that set id for button group using android:id="@+id/button"

Example:

intro_activity_1.xml

```
<Button    android:id="@+id/button"    
android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:layout_weight="1"    
android:background="@android:color/transparent"    
android:text="NEXT" />
```

Now change your java class of first activity. In this example, we change java file of IntroActivity1.java

Example:

IntroActivity1.java

```
//header, import and package data


public class IntroActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button next_btn;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro_activity_1); 

           next_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);//button class

           next_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View arg0){
       //Start new activity class
              Intent myIntent=new Intent(IntroActivity1.this,IntroActivity2.class);
             startActivity(myIntent);
      }
  });
}
```

For More details about activity changer visit : https://answerdone.blogspot.com/2018/01/how-to-change-new-activity-in-android.html