# How to call a Progress Dialog in Fragment?

Tags: android

I have a activity in which adds two Tabs namely frag1 and frag2. In frag1, I am sending server request and a progress dialog is shown to user, But getting error in Dismissing dialog. How can I acheive this problem.

error code:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4274d0d8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-456,144} not attached to window manager
```

Frag1 Dialog code:-

```
private void postDealListingDatatoServer() {
    try {
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password


        Log.e(TAG, "Intial Record Count::" + sz_RecordCount);
        Log.e(TAG, "Intial Last Count::" + sz_LastCount);
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to string

        Log.i(TAG, "Server Request:-" + json);

        m_Dialog = DialogUtils.showProgressDialog(getActivity(), "Loading...");

        final String m_DealListingURL = "http://202.131.144.132:8080//getDealListInJSON";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response:-" + response);
                if (m_Dialog != null && m_Dialog.isShowing()) {
                    m_Dialog.dismiss();
                }
                try {
                    int nResultCodeFromServer = Integer.parseInt(response.getString("resultcode"));
                    if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_TRANSACTION_SUCCESSFUL) {
                        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// get Deal list in array from response
                        s_oDataset.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
                            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
                            item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
                            item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));// get deal name from response
                            item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// get dealcode from response
                            item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));// get deal value from response
                            item.setM_n_Image(m_n_FormImage[i]);//set Image Index wise(Dummy)
                            s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList

                        }
                        if (!s_oDataset.isEmpty()) {// condition if data in arraylist is not empty
                            m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);// create adapter object and add arraylist to adapter
                            m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);//adding adapter to recyclerview
                            m_NoInternetWarning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mSwipeRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        } else {
                            m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);// else Load buttonvisibility set to Gone
                        }
                    }
                    if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_kCONNECTION_LOST) {//server based conditions
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_kDEAL_NOT_FOUND) {// serevr based conditions .....
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_kTECHNICAL_FAILURE) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Technical Failure", getActivity());
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_kTIMED_OUT) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Timed Out", getActivity());
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_kUNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Unknown Error", getActivity());
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_kALREADY_AVAIL_BENEFIT) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "You have already avail the benefit of this deal", getActivity());
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server error:-" + error);
                if (m_Dialog != null && m_Dialog.isShowing()) {
                    m_Dialog.dismiss();
                }
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection lost ! Please try again", getActivity());
                    mSwipeRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    m_NoInternetWarning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No internet connection", getActivity());
                    mSwipeRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    m_NoInternetWarning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

here I am getting error in dismissing dialog.

DialogUtils class code:-

```
public class DialogUtils {

public static ProgressDialog showProgressDialog(Context context, String message) {
    ProgressDialog m_Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    m_Dialog.setMessage(message);
    m_Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    m_Dialog.setCancelable(false);
    m_Dialog.show();
    return m_Dialog;

}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to dismiss your progress dialog using `runOnUiThread()` ?

Answer (score 0):

On the **DialogUtils** class change the first parameter **Context to Activity**

```
public class DialogUtils {

  public static ProgressDialog showProgressDialog(Activity activity, String message) {
    ProgressDialog m_Dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    m_Dialog.setMessage(message);
    m_Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    m_Dialog.setCancelable(false);
    m_Dialog.show();
    return m_Dialog;

  }

}
```

//call in fragment like

```
final ProgressDialog dialog=DialogUtils.showProgressDialog(getActivity(),"Loading...");
```

when you want to dismiss then simply

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

// on pause method

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if ((mDialog != null) && mDialog.isShowing())
        mDialog.dismiss();
    mDialog = null;
}
```

Comment: and what to do in Fragment

Comment: ProgressDialog  dialog=DialogUtils.showProgressDialog(FragmentClass.this, "Loading...");

Comment: why change from context to activity explain in short

Comment: now also getting error:----------java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42787250 V.E..... R......D 0,0-456,144} not attached to window manager

Comment: look at this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518206/what-is-the-difference-between-activity-and-context

Comment: give me solution for that I know context and activity difference