# Show ProgressDialog from another generic Java class

Tags: java, android

I'm using one Generic Java Class named GetVolleyResponse to send and receive data to server using volley.
I want to show progressDialog  from the same class to All other possible calling Activities.I've tried something but it is not working.
GetVolleyResponse.java

```
public class GetVolleyResponse {
    ProgressDialog progress;
    Context ctx;
    AlertDialog.Builder alert;
    GetVolleyResponse(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx=ctx;
        progress=new ProgressDialog(this.ctx);
        progress.setTitle("please wait...");

    }
    public void getResponse(String url, final Map params, final VolleyCallback callback)
    {
         progress.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progress.dismiss();
             callback.onSuccessResponse(response);//Interface for callback Defined by me..
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progress.dismiss();
                String message = null;
                if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    message = "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!";
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    message = "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!";
                } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
                } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    message = "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.";
                }
               callback.onErrorResponse(message);
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return params;
            }
        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(ctx).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

but because of progressDialog app is crashing..

error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.accer.sportsgr, PID: 25143
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.accer.sportsgr/com.example.accer.sportsgr.Updater}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:682)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:316)
                      at com.example.accer.sportsgr.GetVolleyResponse.getResponse(GetVolleyResponse.java:41)
                      at com.example.accer.sportsgr.Updater.onCreate(Updater.java:70)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Here is the call from updater.java

```
 (new GetVolleyResponse(getApplicationContext())).getResponse(Register.serverUrl + UploadUrl, params, new VolleyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccessResponse(String result) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(result);
                        JSONObject jsonObject;
                        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                        {
                            jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            sp_list.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        }
                        sp_list.add("others");
                        setSpinner();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(String message) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

how should i call the above constructor from any actvity

Comment: Izzit crash or the progress dialog not showing?

Comment: app is crashing

Comment: Are you using getApplicationContext() to pass the context while you calling this class?

Comment: yes i've attached complete code.. please take a look.

Comment: I added solution as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(new GetVolleyResponse(this)).getResponse(Register.serverUrl + UploadUrl, params, new VolleyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccessResponse(String result) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(result);
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        sp_list.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    }
                    sp_list.add("others");
                    setSpinner();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(String message) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Use this or youractivity.this as your context parameter instead.Progress Dialog couldn't recognize getApplicationContext() as context I don't know why but if you try to pass create progressDialog with getAplicationContext() as context it will crash.

From Fragment use getActivity. The way you call your class is correct.

Comment: thanq. its working fine. what is the difference between context and this?

Comment: Basically this can be context or activity itself. So there is no difference between context and this just I don't know why while create progressDialog by using getApplicationContext() context it cannot work. For difference between context and activity look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518206/what-is-the-difference-between-activity-and-context