# In Xamarin.Android need use Activity by call from Xamarin.Forms using DependencyService

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-pay

I implement by manual https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial in Xamarin.Forms + Xamarin.Android. I call in Xamarin.Forms:

```
DependencyService.Get<IPay>().Pay();
```

In Xamarin.Android i implement

```
public class Pay_Droid : IPay
{

public void Pay()
{
...
AutoResolveHelper.ResolveTask(
                paymentsClient.LoadPaymentData(request),
                this,
                LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);
...
}

}
```

but have problem in "this" - need use activity. How to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can create public static MainActivity in MainActivity class, then assign current MainActivity to macvivity in MainActivity OnCreate() method:

```
public static MainActivity macvivity;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


        macvivity = this;

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

Finally, you can activity by MainActivity.macvivity

```
public void Pay()
{
...
AutoResolveHelper.ResolveTask(
            paymentsClient.LoadPaymentData(request),
            MainActivity.macvivity,
            LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);
...
}
```

Comment: Have you tested to see if this causes a memory leak? In native Android (Java), maintaining a static reference to a context will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in some of the examples provided by Xamarin on [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView/Droid/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs), you can just use the "[Context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6518310/11104068)" of your app as follows inside your `Pay_Droid` class as follows:

```
Context _context;

public Pay_Droid(Context context) : base(context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public void Pay()
{
    ...
    AutoResolveHelper.ResolveTask(paymentsClient.LoadPaymentData(request), _context, LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin, you can use:

```
public void Pay() => AutoResolveHelper.ResolveTask(
                    PaymentsClient.LoadPaymentData(request),
                    Platform.CurrentActivity,
                    LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);
```