# DialogFragment call failed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, dialogfragment

When you click on the `CardView`, a `DialogFragment` should appear, but the application crashes, writes the following in the logs

```
 Process: com.example.testfuntura, PID: 15385
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
        at com.example.testfuntura.Attraction.AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer.lambda$onBindViewHolder$0(AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer.java:56)
        at com.example.testfuntura.Attraction.-$$Lambda$AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer$4cZEQxk2beWA40yZmNkr6ZJp7o8.onClick(lambda)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5692)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
```

My `Adapter`

```
public class AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer.AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer> {
    public ArrayList<ItemPOA> mFavList;

    public AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer(ArrayList<ItemPOA> favList) {
        mFavList = favList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_attraction_package_offer, parent, false);
        return new AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer(v);
    }

    public static class AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView card_image_1;
        public TextView Package_offer_title;
        public CardView Card;

        public AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.att_po);
            card_image_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_po);
            Package_offer_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tex);

        }
    }
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer holder, int position) {
        ItemPOA currentItem = mFavList.get(position);
        holder.Package_offer_title.setText(currentItem.get_Package_offer_title());
        holder.Card.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogPOA dialog = new DialogPOA();
            dialog.show(((AppCompatActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), "item");
            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();

            bundle1.putString("title_po", currentItem.get_Package_offer_title());
            bundle1.putString("description_po", currentItem.get_Package_offer_description());
            bundle1.putString("cost_po", currentItem.get_Package_offer_cost());
            dialog.setArguments(bundle1);
        });
        holder.getAdapterPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFavList.size();
    }
}
```

I have a similar `Adapter`, but when called, everything works, that is, the problem is not in the `DialogFragment`, since everything works when called from another fragment.

`Fragment` that the `CardView` is in

```
public class FragmentAtt extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<ItemPOA> mFavList;

    String URL = "http://qqqqqqqqq.mcdir.ru/dbpo.php";
    RecyclerView mRec;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    //ImageView GET_PO_IMG;
    String GET_PO_TITLE = "title_po";
    String GET_PO_DESCRIPTION = "description_po";
    String GET_PO_COST = "cost_po";


    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_attraction, container, false);
        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab);
        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mRec = requireView().findViewById(R.id.rec_po);

        mFavList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerViewadapter = new AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer(mFavList);

        recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

        mRec.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRec.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);
        mRec.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
        JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL2_RINK();

        //recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        //SnapHelper snapHelper = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);
        //snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRec);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentAttractionRecyclerView(), "Аттракционы");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentAttractionRecyclerView(), "Видеоигры");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL2_RINK() {
        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
                this::JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL_RINK,
                error ->
                        Log.e("Volley", error.toString())) {
            @Override
            protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                try {
                    Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
                    if (cacheEntry == null) {
                        cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
                    }
                    final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
                    cacheEntry.data = response.data;
                    cacheEntry.softTtl = now;
                    cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
                    String headerValue;
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
                    final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString), cacheEntry);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
                    return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                }
            }
        };
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireContext());
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL_RINK(JSONArray array) {
        mFavList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            ItemPOA GetDataAdapter2 = new ItemPOA();
            JSONObject json;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                GetDataAdapter2.set_Package_offer_title(json.getString(GET_PO_TITLE));
                GetDataAdapter2.set_Package_offer_description(json.getString(GET_PO_DESCRIPTION));
                GetDataAdapter2.set_Package_offer_cost(json.getString(GET_PO_COST));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mFavList.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }
        recyclerViewadapter = new AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer(mFavList);
        mRec.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}
```

An `Adapter` that has the same functionality, but why does it work, explain the difference?

```
public class AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule_2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule_2.SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder> {
    public ArrayList<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2> mSkatingRinkScheduleList;

    public AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule_2(ArrayList<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2> SkatingRinkScheduleList) {
        mSkatingRinkScheduleList = SkatingRinkScheduleList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_srs, parent, false);
        return new SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder(v);
    }

    public static class SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView number_srs, start_time_srs, end_time_srs, cost_1_srs, cost_2_srs;
        public LinearLayout ll_main;


        public SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ll_main = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_main);
            number_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_srs);
            start_time_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.start_time_srs);
            end_time_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.end_time_srs);
            cost_1_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost_1_srs);
            cost_2_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost_2_srs);
        }
    }
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2 currentItem = mSkatingRinkScheduleList.get(position);
        holder.number_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_number());
        holder.start_time_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_start());
        holder.end_time_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_end());
        holder.cost_1_srs.setText(currentItem.get_weekdays());
        holder.cost_2_srs.setText(currentItem.get_weekends_and_holidays());
        holder.ll_main.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogSkatingRinkSchedule dialogSRS = new DialogSkatingRinkSchedule();
            dialogSRS.show(((AppCompatActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), "item");
            Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();

            bundle2.putString("number", currentItem.get_session_number());
            bundle2.putString("start", currentItem.get_session_start());
            bundle2.putString("end", currentItem.get_session_end());
            bundle2.putString("w", currentItem.get_weekdays());
            bundle2.putString("wah", currentItem.get_weekends_and_holidays());
            dialogSRS.setArguments(bundle2);
        });
        holder.getAdapterPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSkatingRinkScheduleList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

Here you are casting a `context` to an `AppCompatActivity` but actually [Activity is not a Context](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518206/what-is-the-difference-between-activity-and-context)

You have two options to solve this:

1. **First option:** Create a listener interface between the activity/fragment that holds the `RecyclerView`, implement it in that activity, and trigger its callback within the `CardView` `onClickListener` `onClick()` callback.
2. **Second option:** Change the constructor signature of the `AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer` adapter to accept a `FragmentManager` instance; save it as a class field like below, and reflect that on the instantiation of the adapter

```
public class AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer.AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer> {
    public ArrayList<ItemPOA> mFavList;
    
    private FragmentManager fragmentMgr;
    
    public AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer(ArrayList<ItemPOA> favList, FragmentManager fManger) {
        mFavList = favList;
        fragmentMgr = fManger;
    }

    //......... suppressed code
    
    
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer holder, int position) {
        ItemPOA currentItem = mFavList.get(position);
        holder.Package_offer_title.setText(currentItem.get_Package_offer_title());
        
        holder.Card.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogPOA dialog = new DialogPOA();
            dialog.show(fragmentMgr, "item");
            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();

            bundle1.putString("title_po", currentItem.get_Package_offer_title());
            bundle1.putString("description_po", currentItem.get_Package_offer_description());
            bundle1.putString("cost_po", currentItem.get_Package_offer_cost());
            dialog.setArguments(bundle1);
        });
        holder.getAdapterPosition();
    }

    //......... suppressed code

}
```

Comment: I updated the question, could you see what is the difference between `Adapter`? I just don't understand why I repeated the same thing, but it doesn't work

Comment: I couldn't see the difference between both .. but the casting is not that right .. are the dialogs the same?

Comment: No, `dialog` other, strange for some reason it does not work with this adapter