# Change Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How can I change the Activity in Android ?
I don't want to create a new Activity, I just want to change it.

Comment: what you want to change in activity?

Comment: You can switch between Activities via `Intents`. your question is little confusing.

Comment: What have you do so far?

Comment: replace the ui with setContentView().

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers. I should be more precise, sry.
All answers solved my Problem. :D Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of tutorials about this, also on Stackoverflow.
Reading the Docs would help too...
But here is the Solution you are searching for:
[On Android, how do you switch activities programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591465/on-android-how-do-you-switch-activities-programatically)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something as below

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, TargetAvitivityName.class);
startActivity(myIntent)
```